# Inheritance: how can I use variables from child class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

How can I use variables from a child class in Program.cs? I can only use the ones declared in Player class. However I was able to "merge" the child class parameters with the parent's variables
[image: Screenshot of container]

But when I try to use those variables they're missing:
[image: Screenshot of variables missing]

How to call the variables from a child class? If it's possible.

```
abstract class Player
{
    public string Team { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string surName { get; set; }
    public DateTime birthDate { get; set; }
    public int gamesCount { get; set; }
    public Player()
    { }
    public Player(string Team, string Name, string surName, DateTime birthDate, int gamesCount)
    {
        this.Team = Team;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.surName = surName;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.gamesCount = gamesCount;
    }

}


class BasketballPlayers : Player
{
    public int Rebounds { get; set; }
    public int Assists { get; set; }
    public int scorePoints { get; set; }
    public BasketballPlayers()
    { }
    public BasketballPlayers(string Team, int gamesCount, string Name, string surName, DateTime birthDate, int scorePoints, int Rebounds, int Assists)
        : base(Team, Name, surName, birthDate, gamesCount)
    {
        this.scorePoints = scorePoints;
        this.Rebounds = Rebounds;
        this.Assists = Assists;
    }
class FootballPlayers : Player
{
    public int yellowCards { get; set; }
    public int scorePoints { get; set; }
    public FootballPlayers()
    { }
    public FootballPlayers(string Team, int gamesCount, string Name, string surName, DateTime birthDate, int scorePoints, int yellowCards)
        : base(Team, Name, surName, birthDate, gamesCount)
    {
        this.yellowCards = yellowCards;
        this.scorePoints = scorePoints;
    }
```

UPDATE:  `PlayersContainer bPlayers = new PlayersContainer(100)` for basketball players 
          `PlayersContainer fPlayers = new PlayersContainer(100);`  this for football players.

```
    static void ReadDataFromFiles(string basketBallFile, string footBallFile, string teamInfoFile, PlayersContainer bPlayers, PlayersContainer fPlayers)
    {
        ReadPlayerData(basketBallFile, bPlayers);
        ReadPlayerData(footBallFile, fPlayers);
    }
    static void ReadPlayerData(string filePath, PlayersContainer Players)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string line = null;
            string playerType = null;
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                playerType = line;
            }
            int i = 0;
            while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(';');
                string Team = values[0];
                string surName = values[1];
                string Name = values[2];
                DateTime birthDate = DateTime.Parse(values[3]);
                int gamesCount = int.Parse(values[4]);
                int scorePoints = int.Parse(values[5]);

                switch (filePath)
                {
                    case "../../Krepsininkai.csv":
                        int Rebounds = int.Parse(values[6]);
                        int Assists = int.Parse(values[7]);
                        BasketballPlayers bPlayer = new BasketballPlayers(Team, gamesCount, Name, surName, birthDate, scorePoints, Rebounds, Assists);
                        Players.AddPlayer(bPlayer);
                        break;
                    case "../../Futbolininkai.csv":
                        int yellowCards = int.Parse(values[6]);
                        FootballPlayers fPlayer = new FootballPlayers(Team, gamesCount, Name, surName, birthDate, scorePoints, yellowCards);
                        Players.AddPlayer(fPlayer);
                        break;

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

when i debug, i can see that those exclusive parameters are added, I mean `Rebounds, Assists, scorePoints` for baskteball players and `yellowCards, scorePoints` for football players. But then i try to access them I need a methods for that or what? I can only call base class parameters.

Comment: please show how you are using this in the other class. if it's just declared as  `Player`, then it will need to be declared as `BasketballPlayers`

Comment: You can't access members defined in a child directly from the base class. You need to use either `virtual` methods/properties or downcast to the appropriate type

Comment: Could you give me an example of how should that virtual method look like?

Answer (score -2):

It would be best to design this need by creating an Abstract Base Class with properties you will want to call. Just have the derived or child class override the property(ies). Then when one has a reference or via an interface related to the base, if it's instance is truly the child, then the Child's property is called/used.